# Slick 3 - upsert works too slow

Tags: scala, slick

I use flowing code for `upsert` list `items`

```
case class Item(id: String, text: String)

class Items(tag: Tag) extends Table[Item](tag, "items"){
    ...
}

val tbl = TableQuery[Items]

def insertItems(items: List[Item]):Future[Int] = {
    val q = DBIO.sequence(items.map(tbl.insertOrUpdate).toSeq).map(_.sum)
    db.run(q)
}
```

For `items` list with length 2000, `upsert` takes ~10 seconds. It's too long...

I think, most part time takes compiling queries.

How should I rewrite `insertItems` for acceleration it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `compiled queries`( [docs](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#compiled-queries) ). AFAIK, Compiled queries for insert are available after slick 2.0.

Also, to insert a list, you should do a batch operation rather than inserting a record one by one.

So, in Slick-3.0, for insert, you should do:

```
val tblCompiled = Compiled(TableQuery[Items])
tblCompiled ++= items
```

Then run another query to get the sum of the desired column.

EDIT: I don't think, slick supports bulk insertOrUpdate statements. If the underlying db supports bulk insertOrUpdate, the fastest approach will be to write plain SQL. Otherwise compiled `insertOrUpdate` query should be decently fast.

The code should be something like

```
items.map(tblCompiled.insertOrUpdate)
```